# How to display the return value?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a simple Trignometry calculator. How do I use the value returned from `Area`? I want to output it to the console.

```cs
using System;

namespace Trignometery
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Area(0, 0);
        }

        static double Area(double height, double Base)
        {
            // Give Instructions
            Console.WriteLine("Enter The Height And Base:\n");

            //Take Input
            height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Base = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            double answer = (height * Base) / 2;

            // Give Answer
            return answer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Console.Write(Area(0,0); You need to add Console.Read() to wait for user input before closing console.

Answer (score 1):

In your main method, you're calling your `Area` method like this:

```
Area(0, 0);
```

You're not storing the return value (you're discarding it). You should write something like this:

```
double calculatedArea = Area(0, 0);
Console.WriteLine("The calculated area was {0}", calculatedArea);
```

Or you can do it all in one line:

```
Console.WriteLine("The calculated area was {0}", Area(0, 0));
```

I notice that your method expects two parameters: `height` and `Base`, but you're not actually using the values passed in. You should instead define local variables for these and make your method parameterless:

```
static double Area()
{
    // Give Instructions
    Console.WriteLine("Enter The Height And Base:\n");

    //Take Input
    double height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    double Base = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    double answer = (height * Base) / 2;

    // Give Answer
    return answer;
}
```

Your method call would then look like this:

```
double calculatedArea = Area();
```

The code now more accurately reflects what you're doing.